# CMake cannot find ninja when run in QtCreator

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, ninja

I have a call to find_program in my CMakeLists.txt file to find the path to Ninja. This returns the right value when I run ninja via the command line but fails when I run it within QtCreator:

```
find_program(
    CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM
    NAME ninja
    PATHS /opt/local/bin
  )
  message(${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM})
```

In ninja this returns:

```
/opt/local/bin/ninja
```

In QtCreator this returns:

```
/usr/bin/make
```

Why would CMake not find something that is present in the $PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [find_program()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html):

> A cache entry named by VAR is created to store the result of this command. If the program is found the result is stored in the variable and the search will not be repeated unless the variable is cleared.

In your case `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` happens to be cached as `/usr/bin/make` (probably, it was at some point set by QtCreator), so `find_program()` does nothing.

A proper way to switch between `make` and `ninja` would be to use [CMake generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

Answer (score 0):

The variable [CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.html) is **cached** by the CMake generator. `find_program` does not update a cached variable unless it contains `*-NOTFOUND`.

You need to use other variable in `find_program` call, and then update `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` variable with `set(CACHE ... FORCE)`:

```
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM <new-value> CACHE FILEPATH "" FORCE)
```

---

Note, that switching `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` from `make` to `ninja` is not a right way for change [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generators.7.html). You need to pass a proper CMake generator via `-G` option to `cmake` itself.